# Android Room Group By Month and Year

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am grouping the rows by day with following query:

```
select * from parse where trackId = :trackId group by date(parseDate / 1000,'unixepoch')
```

This one works well. But I need the same query for month and year. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strftime()` to get the year and month in the format `YYYY-MM` and group by that:

```
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', parseDate / 1000, 'unixepoch')
```

Note that, `group by` with `select *` and without any aggregation  does not really make sense.